# Eclipse & GWT - Associate .ui.xml with corresponding .java file

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

The thing is this:

[image]

`HomeViewImpl.ui.xml` gets separated from its corresponding Java file `HomeViewImpl.java` in the Project Explorer of Eclipse. This is getting increasingly annoying as the amount of files inside a package increases.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to either sort the files inside the Java packages strictly by name or to associate the .ui.xml files such that they are child elements of the `<file-name>.java` node in the tree?

---

[Feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488824) on bugs.eclipse.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in Project Explorer file sorting is not an option. 
But if it's not a problem to you, you can switch to the Navigator view which allows you to sort files the way you want.
Window > Show View > Navigator

Once you switch to navigator you get the option to sort files by name.
[image]

Comment: Hmm.. it's not the Package Explorer but this seems to be as good as it gets. Never thought of the idea to check out other views after Package and Project explorer are not able to do this. I guess the bounty goes to you if no better solution arrives :)

Comment: Well I guess there is no better solution. I have added a [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488824).

Answer (score 0):

I keep composities and .ui.xml views in a package structure that seperates them by model.  As long as you aren't mixing views within a package, it will stay manageable.

[Example](https://github.com/aglassman/jgoo/tree/master/JGoo/src/com/jgoo/client/domain)

Comment: I don't see how this would make it better. The ordering would be the same, the only difference is that I have one or more packages in between.

Comment: Keep views, models, controllers, activities, and places in different packages.  This keeps things nicely separated.

Comment: I prefer to have the presenter, model and the view as well as the ui.xml file in one package. It does not make sense to separate them. If I work on one thing then I don't want to have 4 different packages open in my project explorer. I just had a major refactor session to go away from the approach you're suggesting. Sorry, it's just not for me ^^

Comment: I suppose it is a personal preference.  Also depends on if you use hierarchical, or flat view of packages in eclipse.  My approach works best with hierarchical view since you have many more packages, and displaying them all would be a waste of screen space.